# How to read switch state from smart plug from busybox

Tags: gpio, busybox

I have a couple of Maginon SP-1E smart plugs which can be triggered remotely. I manage them through HA, but did not find a way yet to just read out the state of the switch. There is a command to switch on or off and a result is returned. The plug is running Busybox (v1.12.1 (2014-07-31 06:32:52 CEST) multi-call binary) and is somewhat stripped down, but telnet, ifconfig, nvram_get, nvram_daemon, nvram_set, flash, gpio are all binaries that are available for use.

To turn on:
http://192.168.0.52/goform/SystemCommand?command=GpioForCrond+1

Returns:

```
gpio_set_dir: gpio=2, dir=0
gpio_set_dir: gpio=1, dir=1
InitGpio() success, fd = 3
Get GPIO1 = [01]
```

To turn off:
http://192.168.0.52/goform/SystemCommand?command=GpioForCrond+0

Returns:

```
gpio_set_dir: gpio=2, dir=0
gpio_set_dir: gpio=1, dir=1
InitGpio() success, fd = 3
Get GPIO1 = [00]
```

So clearly there seems to be a way to toggle (and read) the switch state, but I cannot find a way to do so. Any hints? The source code for the plug is available [here](http://gpl.supra-elektronik.com/).

Comment: So, have you downloaded it and checked? What is the result? Tell us more!

Comment: Yes, but I'm not a real programmer, so I have no clue what the C code is doing. I start to understand why Java and Python were invented after C. :-)